# Bootsrap responsive table not working in main table td cell

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootsrap responsive table working like this:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table"><tr><td>responsive working</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

But when I used in a main table cell (td) inner responsive table not working. What can we do for fix it?

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>

<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table">now not responsive</table>
</div>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: why put another table inside a table?

Comment: @Swellar you are right divs usefull instead tables for front website but this is for admin panel. tables old habits for me and it's easy for me instead of divs. i am using first table for main box (first tr for module title and second tr for module contents etc..)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this,The problem was that you haven't specified default table class which comes with bootstrap "`table`" you have to mention it first. Not `table-responsive`, it must have to be `table table-responsive`

```html
<html>
<head>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<table class="table table-responsive">
  <th colspan="3">Outer Table</th>
  <tr>
    <td>This is row one, column 1</td>
    <td>This is row one, column 2</td>
    
    <td>
      <table class="table table-responsive">
        <th colspan="3">Second Inner Table</th>
        <tr>
          <td>This is row one, column 1</td>
          <td>This is row one, column 2</td>
          <td>This is row one, column 3</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for answer, I did try to fix it in my code but responsive not worked (scrollbar didn't come) i will try with all your code in new page.

Comment: I did try a lot of combination but not working, can you look this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zwyaJX

Comment: @webmaster now check this out https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pPqKmx you have added unneccary divs

Comment: it's possible text in only one line? I see in two lines. (i did try in table style : width:auto; white-space:nowrap; overflow-x:scroll; but not working)

Comment: @webmaster that's because its inside container div, it automatically goes down :)

Comment: i removed container div but goes down again. can we do for fix this? or we can't use responsive table in table cell?